# Are git versions compatible between windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, git, version

does somebody know, if windows and linux versions are compatible?

I need to know because I need to share the disk where my local reposities are between linux and win, which runs in virtualBox on the linux pc.

I develop on linux, but I need to use git on windows when I work remote (because of a VPN issue). Another option would be to always use git from windows, but I prefer not to start vbox.

Has somebody done this? I suppose it could be a bit risky, or would it be OK to rely on the versions to be 100% compatible. I would not like to have my repository corruptet...

Cheers Henning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as you're concerned about the database format they are compatible.  Moreover, such compatibility is required even for "non-native" solutions like the `JGit` or `libgit2` libraries.

I can only see two possible problems:

- From time to time Git might change behaviour in a way not compatible with some of its past versions (but very rarely and with bold warnings in release notes documents long before the change is made).

  So find out what versions you're running (`git --version`) in both worlds and if there's a major difference between them (in the `X` number of `1.X.Y` version) consider reading the changelog for the one which has a greater `X` for possible gotchas.
- Potential filesystem issues: these days you can mount an `NTFS` volume R/W when running a recent Linux kernel, and same goes about Ext2 (but not Ext3 and certainly not Ext4) on Windows but you might, in theory, accidently hit some problem with these drivers — of course, they haven't received that much love their native variants have.